# Trouble sending "Hello World" to arduino mega 2560 from raspberry pi

Tags: serial-port, arduino, raspberry-pi

All -

I have followed these instructions:

http://www.mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-spi/

However when I get to the last step

```
sudo ./spidev_test
```

I never see "HELLO WORLD" in my Serial Monitor console even though my baud rate is 115200.

I did try to run the following command

```
ls -al /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/spi/
```

and it only has two kernel drivers:

- spi-bcm2708.ko
- spidev.ko

Could this be the problem ? According to the website I should have two more:

- spi-bitbang.ko
- spi-gpio.ko

How would I get a copy of these two drivers it is the problem?

When I run the "spidev_test" program I get some output that says something about "8 bits per word", but no error message.

Comment: Show us exactly what the output is, instead of "something about..."

Comment: The tutorial you are referencing to has comments enabled. Why don't you ask there?